# Why I get different time zone in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, git, github, gitpython

I am extracting data from GitHub into my database (PostgreSQL) using git in python.
I tried to extract DateTime by using committed_datetime and insert this data into my  database; what happens that I got different time zone on my database, for example, the exact date on GitHub is 2011-06-18 22:10:34+02:00, but when it been stored into my database became
2011-06-18 21:10:34+01. I tried to change the data type in my database into text, but it still did not work... so My question is :  if the data type in the table is text, I did not get the exact data that I extracted from Github commit?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We need a [mre], not a description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: `but when it been stored into my database` **How** did you store it?. BTW the timestamps are basically the same. They are only represented wrt different timezones.

Comment: I used query where I insert the extracted data into my database , however I set datatype = text , so the data should be stored in the same way that was extracted

Answer (score 1):

That is how `timestamp with time zone` works in PostgreSQL:

```
SHOW TimeZone;

   TimeZone    
═══════════════
 Europe/Vienna
(1 row)

SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2021-10-13 09:00:00-07';

      timestamptz       
════════════════════════
 2021-10-13 18:00:00+02
(1 row)
```

Note that the actual point in time is the same.

PostgreSQL stores `timestamp with time zone` as UTC timestamp internally, and when it is formatted as a string, that is done according to the current setting of the `TimeZone` parameter.

You can either adjust `TimeZone` to match your expectations, or you can use `AT TIME ZONE` to convert it to a `timestamp without time zone` that represents what a wall clock in that time zone would show:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2021-10-13 09:00:00-07' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles';

      timezone       
═════════════════════
 2021-10-13 09:00:00
(1 row)
```

If you want to preserve the time zone setting along with the timestamp, you have to store the timestamp in an extra column.

Comment: I have to get the date in one column like this 2011-06-18 22:10:34+02:00 , so do you think I should change type of column for something different than string ??

Comment: Never, ever, store timestamps as strings in a database.